# Change slider bar as you drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, range

I have a Javascript slider bar which uses an array for the options. However, It does not change as you drag.

```js
var img = document.getElementById('img');
var img_array = ['http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png', 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/img_html5_html5.gif'];

function setImage(obj) {
  var value = obj.value;
  img.src = img_array[value];

}
```

```html
<img id='img' src='http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png' />
<input onchange='setImage(this)' type="range" min="0" max="1" value="0" step="1" />
```

can anyone give me some guidance on how to change the image while I am dragging the slider, rather than when I let go of the mouse button

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, working for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/d5o10fb7/4/

Comment: No, I wanted the image to change as I am interacting with the scrollbar. At the moment you have to let go before the image changes.

Comment: The change event is only triggered at the end of the interaction, so you need to use something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544890/onchange-event-on-input-type-range-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-while-dragging)

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use oninput instead of onchange

([Get value of slider while it's being moved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254010/get-value-of-slider-while-its-being-moved))

```js
var img = document.getElementById('img');
var img_array = ['http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png', 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/img_html5_html5.gif'];

function setImage(obj) {
  var value = obj.value;
  img.src = img_array[value];

}
```

```html
<img id='img' src='http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png' />
<input oninput='setImage(this)' type="range" min="0" max="1" value="0" step="1" />
```